# Django, views, when I import the model it won't take the method "objects"

Tags: django

I have done the makemigrations and the migrate and I see the tables created in postgresql, but the function in the view will not pick the .objects.all() method

This is one snippet of the models.py

```
class Donor(models.Model):
    thename = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
```

tHE html page

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Donor

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   list = Donor.objects.all()  #The word objects gets highlighted bc it is not accepted as method
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'lista':thelist})
```

UPDATE:
The error persists, the (all) was a typing error when writing here, but like I said, the Donor.model will not accept the objects method.

The html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
print(thelist)
{% for x in thelist %}
{{ x.name }} <br>
{% endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct here `list = Donor.objects(all)`. It should be `list = Donor.objects.all()`

Comment: i noticed that, sorry that was not the error, i corrected that straightaway but you were quicker. The error of "objects" being highlighted persists

Comment: What is error says when you run the server?

Comment: The objects attribute is added dynamically to the model by Django, Your IDE would not know that and consider it erroneous, it will work properly.

Comment: I get your point Abdul and Shafik but when I try to reload the server, it simply refuses to connect, something that did not happen before the error.

Comment: Add the whole error message in your question.

Comment: Your code `return render(request, 'home.html', {'lista':thelist})` may have a typo. You are calling the list `list` and then passing the context `thelist` you should change that line to `return render(request, 'home.html', {'lista':list})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix in the `index` method

`list` is the reserved keyword in Python. So, just rename it.

```
def index(request):
   thelist = Donor.objects.all()  #The word objects gets highlighted bc it is not accepted as method
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'lista':thelist})
```